# Flutter can not create TCP SOCKET for P2P connection

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sockets, p2p

I'm aiming to make a p2p chat app with Flutter/Dart. My Concept is: There are peers and a server. Server only works for peers to find each other. After 2 peers find each other, they will connect to each other via Socket and will have nothing to do with server. They'll handle rest (messaging part) via their own sockets. I made server part. Peers successfully connects to server and send informations (IP and PORT number which is used in creating it's own Socket). The problem is, a peer can't connect to another.

I mean, lets assume we have Peer A and Peer B. Peer A's IP is 155.252.100.13(Public ip) and Port number used for socket is 12456 (I've just made up these numbers, they are not real)
The code I used in peer a is this:
(Peer A runs on an emulator, it has connection to the Internet I checked)

```
final Future<ServerSocket> mySocket = ServerSocket.bind("0.0.0.0", 12345);
```

then, Peer B tries to connect it like this:
(Peer B runs on physical Android Device. I connected it to Android studoio via USB cable)

```
p2pSocket = await Socket.connect("155.252.100.13", 12345);
```

and I get error on Peer A:

[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: StreamSink is closed

#0      _StreamSinkImpl.add (dart:io/io_sink.dart:134:7)

#1      _Socket.add (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2203:38)

#2      main. (package:encrypt/peer.dart:225:24)

#3      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1586:10)

#4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)

#5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)

#6      _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:774:19)

#7      _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:648:7)

#8      _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:596:5)

#9      _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2324:41)

#10     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1586:10)

#11     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)

#12     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stre<…>

Sometimes I don't get any error on peer A. peer B just doesn't connect. No error message. Just does nothing. Comes to connect line and waits forever or stops I don't know.

What's wrong? The hall idea? Or technique? What should I do?

Comment: `After 2 peers find each other, they will connect to each other via Socket and will have nothing to do with server. ` That will only work if not both use mobile connection.

Comment: If one peer knows the ip of the other and the other uses mobile connection it will not work.

Comment: If one peer knows the ip of the other and the other is on wifi behind a router then it will only work if the router forwards the used port to that peer.

Comment: Makes sense. What do you think about "Unhandled Exception: Bad state: StreamSink is closed" error? And how can I be sure that router forwards that port to peer? @blackapps

Comment: I do not think about exceptions. And if you are not sure then what is your doubt?

Comment: I mean how can I achieve this? @blackapps

Comment: What is 'this'? exactly?

Comment: I mean how can I make router forward the used port to that peer

Comment: That question does not belong here. Ask on a network site. Router settings.